# What are some good informal beginner level books for studying combinatorial geometry?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

I recently got very interested in puzzles (e.g. packing and tiling puzzles, Kobon triangle problem etc.) involving combinatorial geometry problems. But I don't have the background to understand the proofs of the theorems related to these puzzles. What good books (written in informal style) should I refer to? Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Combinatorial Geometry: 37 (Wiley Series in Discrete Mathematics and Optimization)
link to buy the book: https://www.amazon.in/Combinatorial-Geometry-Discrete-Mathematics-Optimization/dp/0471588903
Try this Buddy

Comment: Thank you Jayaprakash. I'll have a look.